# csv parsing, exploding avoiding ""

Tags: php, csv, explode

I have a csv file (really big) that I'm parsing with php.

Now is made like this.

```
x,y,z,value,etc
```

but sometimes there is this:

```
x,"blah,blah,blah",z,value,etc
```

doing this: `explode(',',$string);`
In case of a "" value also explode everything within.

```
array([0]=>x,[1]=>"blah,[2]=>blah,[3]=>blah"....)
```

What can I do to have this:

```
array([0]=>x,[1]=>"blah,blah,blah",[2]=>z....)
```

instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Don't use explode, use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

For parsing just a string use [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) if you have PHP >= 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you and had to use the method you are saying. I would parse the string for text within the quotes via a regular expression.

Replace the , with a * (for example)

x,"blah*blah*blah",z,value,etc

then explode the string once again with the ,

Now you should get an approriate array but now you have the bla*bla*bla.

Then just do str_replace on the array

And in that way you should work..

This only applies if you have strict rules how to parse.. (in this case by explode);